# AMD/Dojo 1.7 Single Page App: Where to put the Require()'s?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I've got a large scale single page app that I'm migrating to Dojo 1.7/AMD loader syntax.

I've got a main JSP that loads everything, and then a multitude of JSP pages that are used for dynamic content generation.

Is it a better design decision to add the require(){} block around the entire application, or around each instance of a requisite module?

Or some combination?  Add the most common require()'s to the main page, and then go through and find other instances that need to be wrapped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should lazy-load as much as possible; perhaps at the "dynamic content" JSP page level.  It makes it very clear about what each page requires, and keeping the requires() close to the code that uses the imported module is clearer.

It also reduces the amount of time the main page takes to load, which means the user can interact with the application in a shorter amount of time.  This is a Good Thing.

Comment: The key thing is to build a base layer using the build process that provides modules you can justify loading on every page. So, for us, it ends up containing the most common dijit form input widgets (text, select, button, etc) and all those dependencies. After that, the additional layers shouldn't include the modules already provided by the base layer, but should require the base layer as a dependency.

Comment: Ah, good tip.  I'm still learning how the Dojo build process works.

Comment: @Andrew - It would be awesome if you would paste in your general-page include.  I'm still a bit vague on whether you need to explicitly include things like 'dojo' and 'dojox'.

Comment: @mtyson - Generally your layer doesn't need dojo/dijit/dojox dependencies unless that's what you want included. so, if you have a collection of widgets (myCompany.MyWidget,etc) then your layer file would be the list of widgets you made, if they depend on dojo/dijit/dojox stuff, it will be automatically included. If however, you use dijit/dojo stuff directly, you'll want to enumerate those in your layer file too. It's very situational.

Comment: @mtyson - Look at the build report generated by the build tools and it will list which modules are included in the layer.